# Which one is grammatically correct, with "the" or without "the"? Why?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

> 1. An Introduction to ***the*** History and Principles of Heraldry.
> 2. An Introduction to History and Principles of Heraldry.

Which one is grammatically correct, with "the" or without "the"? Why?

Comment: Unless you're talking about history in general, prefer the definite article there: *An Introduction to the History and Principles of Heraldry*.

Comment: @Robusto: Which preference causes many people to suppose what Gibbon wrote was entitled [***The** decline and fall...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=26cMAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22decline+and+fall+of+the+roman%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YTRjVcvfK8blUoLrgPgE&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22decline%20and%20fall%20of%20the%20roman%22&f=false), but in fact that initial article was never included. I think the question is Off Topic because "grammatically correct" isn't really relevant to book titles.

Comment: This is a title. Titles do not follow any consistent pattern of article use. Unless it's your book and you're in charge of the title, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical, but the form with "the" is overwhelmingly more common in phrases of this sort.

I find it hard to explain why. I think it's something to do with the fact that the "of" phrase limits it and makes it in a sense more definite. But I suspect it's just one of those oddities of English: we don't say "the history" but we do say "the history of ... "

(On the other hand, we would say "methods of ... " rather than "the methods of ... ").